# How can I write to all users to their HKEY_CURRENT_USER using inno-setup

Tags: inno-setup, registry

I'm installing third party software that must read from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE... using inno-setup.
I need to write this value to all users, how can I do it?

Comment: Load the default user hive, make your changes and close the hive. Test by logging in as a new user https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/how-can-i-configure-default-settings-new-users

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can't do this (in a simple and supported manner). To do this, all user hives would need to be loaded and that is not necessarily the case for all users.

<strike>You can write to the default profile under `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT` which will affect all *new* user profiles, or you can write to the machine hive under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.</strike>

Probably the preferred option would be to run the setup separately for every user, e.g. as part of a logon script.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: .DEFAULT is not a default registry for new user profiles, it's a registry for the “NT Authority/Local System”. Default registry for all new users is located in C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\NTUSER.DAT hive which can be opened and edited by regedit

Comment: @zihotki: Thanks for your comment, you're absolutely correct. It is explained by Raymond Chen here: **[The .Default user is not the default user](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/02/1786493.aspx)**

Answer (score 4):

As 0xA3 says, you cannot. One of the major reasons is [Roaming Profiles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/30/434209.aspx). Basically, the profile data for a particular user may not even be present on the machine, at this time, or it may be a stale copy.

If you need a setting that applies to all users, then obvious HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE would be preferred. If you need a setting that will be the *default* for all users, then store that *default* in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, and copy it into a users profile if they don't currently have a valud there.

Comment: Another reason you cannot is that new users may be added after the software is installed.

Comment: `HKLM` default copy to empty `HKCU` is the "best practice" in this regard.  As an IT professional, this is what I expect from software installed to `Program Files`.  Software that's installed per-user (in AppData, like Google Chrome), I expect it to write to that users `HKCU` and ignore `HKLM`

Comment: Additionally, `HKLM` is to `HKCU` as `C:\ProgramData\` is to a user's `AppData` `Local` and `Roaming`

Answer (score 0):

You might consider on app run, looking for current user keys and if not found, message for a repair reg that would add keys to the current user. I have a similar situation and that's what I do.

Answer (score 0):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER is just a pointer to: HKEY_USERS\ Security ID (SID) so if you really wanted to do this then you could iterate over all HKEY_USERS (however this only includes users currently logged on to the system).

A better solution might be to check in your app whether the settings have been setup for HKEY_CURRENT_USER and if not copy from a HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.  In this way your app will handle new users added after installation.

Comment: Tanks but it will copy the values only after log in?