# How can I change the system date format using a batch file/script?

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, format

I am a software tester and I often need to switch my short date format from M/dd/yy to d/M/yy because of Australian/New Zealand customers using a different date format.  It is a pain in the ass to open up the clock, click change date and time, click change calendar settings, select the different date format from the drop-down and apply it before testing.  Especially since when I am done I have to go through all of that again to set it back.  This happens often enough that I want to automate the process like I have with some others (uninstall latest beta and installing the newest build, etc).

Does anyone know how I would go about accessing these settings in a batch file or in some kind of script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /f /v sShortDate /t REG_SZ /d "d/M/yy" >nul
echo %date%
```

It's better to change the user's registry instead of the global.

Answer (score 0):

```
HKEY_USERS\.Default\Control Panel\International
```

try this reg key with REG add and such
Add or edit the sShortDate string value with 
        MM/dd/yyyy,
        M/d/yy, 
        M/d/yyyy, 
        MM/dd/yy, 
        yy/MM/dd, 
        yyyy-MM-dd, or
        dd-MMM-yy.

Comment: I said that "try this reg key with REG add and such". REG... ;(

Comment: Duh!  I don't know how I didn't see that.

Comment: HKEY_USERS\.Default is not a default registry for new user profiles, it's a registry for the “NT Authority/Local System”.
See zihotki's comment on this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4098105/3345085